# Activating touchpad with Windows 10

Tags: windows

Since I upgraded my Acer V5 laptop from Win 8.1 to Win 10 last week, I cannot seem to be able to use my synaptic touch pad to scroll, anymore.

Is there a solution to  this?

I cannot find the answer here.

Comment: Did you update the touchpad driver to one that supports Windows 10?

Answer (score -1):

I too had the same issue. Things you can do

1. Right click on This PC -> Manage -> Device Manager and then right click Mice and other pointing devices -> Scan for hardware changes.
2. Uninstall your existing driver and update it from manufacturer's site.
3. Or Run windows updates. It will install the driver automatically.